# Codeigniter session expiration after 5 mins

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I am using session for OTP(One Time Password) as `$this->session->set_userdata('otp')`. I want to set expiration time of this session as 5 mins(300sec). For all other sessions in my code, I want expiration time as normal session time. How to do this?

Comment: Can't you use cookie or codeigniter `flash_data` ?

Comment: I am using codeigniter 2.2 for my project, so flash_data is not possible

Comment: @SankarV No, flash_data only lives 1 request, so that's not an option. What you however could do is store the time of adding the session and then doing a check whether the token has expired or not. Codeigniter itself does not ship with a library for this.

Comment: @Jordy .. Oops.. Sorry.. I mean `tempdata`. Can't we use codeigniter `tempdata` ?

Comment: @Thedeveloper You can try with database if you dont want to change anything. `store into database with timestamp on user input check that **current timestamp >   timestamp + 5 minutes** then give error message and if not let user pass that condition  ` hope you get me... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first - you need to get the terms right. A "session" is the whole thing, while as I understand it you want to set a TTL for only a certain session "item".

That being said, you can't do this with CodeIgniter 2, and you shouldn't - the 2.x version tree is no longer supported.

Upgrade to CodeIgniter 3 and you'll be able to use the "[tempdata](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#tempdata)" feature, which does exactly what you want:

```
// This will make $_SESSION['otp'] available only for the next 5 minutes
$this->session->set_tempdata('otp', $your_value, 300);
```

Incidentally, 5 minutes is also the default TTL even if you skip that parameter.

Comment: I tried to upgrade from codeigniter version 2 to 3 by replacing system folder. But It gave me certain errors. How to upgrade??

Comment: By following the upgrade instructions: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrading.html

Comment: I followed that one, but still got some errors. I will going to upgrade it someday. Can you please suggest me another option?? I am in hurry to write the code. I have to make it work

Comment: No, there is no other option ... And the upgrade usually takes less than an hour, there's no reason to avoid it.

Comment: I followed that one, but still got some errors. I will going to upgrade it someday. Can you please suggest me another option?? I am in hurry to write the code. I have to make it work

Comment: No, there is no other option! That won't change no matter how many times you ask me.